# When I run a test suite with ChromeDrive Chrome is opened at every test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use the same code with Appium driver and Java , TestNG but with ChromeDriver I changed the configuration by adding that code :

```
File file = new File("C:/QA/Emna/chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

The problem is that any test case the chrome window is opened a new one, even if my tests are in a correct order with Priority (by TestNG).

Is there a way to work in only one window?

Comment: Instantiate `ChromeDriver` once and use it until you are done with you test cases execution. Eg: `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` can be in any method annotated as `@BeforeSuite`, `@BeforeTest`, `@BeforeGroups` or `@BeforeClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem by this way in `@BeforeClass`:

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void before() {
        // check active session
        System.out.println("Becore Test Method");
        File file = new File("C:/QA/Emna/chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        wd = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

I made an instance like that:

```
static WebDriver driver ;
```

Then in every test I put the following :

```
@Test
public static void run1() {
//my tests using wd
}

@Test
public static void run2() {
//my tests using wd
}
```

Comment: Why 2 instance variables? `driver` itself will be available throughout the tests execution in the class, once initialized.

Comment: Yes you are right ! I have followed the same old logic when one driver is WebDriver and the other is ChromeDriver i'll update it.
Thanks for your attention Atul ;)

Answer (score 1):

`WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` is what opens a new browser each time. Move it to `@BeforeClass` section and use the same instance in all the tests.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move you code snippet in any `@Before` type of TestNG methods. Lets say your all test cases are in a `TestNG` class then

**Here is how it should look like**:

```
@BeforeClass
public void deSetup(){
        File file = new File("C:/QA/Emna/chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

But if this is not the case, what I mean by this, that your test cases are spread across the multiple TestNG classes then the best way is to have a `Singleton` class to load and initialize the ChromeDriver. Call method of the `Singleton` class to instantiate the ChromeDriver in any one of method annotated as `@BeforeSuite` `@BeforeTest` or `@BeforeGroups`. And have a reference variable of `WebDriver` type in evelry test class and assigne the previously initialized ChromeDriver to this reference variable in `@BeforeClass` method.

In such a way, ChromeDriver will be instantiated only once when any one of `@BeforeSuite` `@BeforeTest` or `@BeforeGroups` method runs and will be available in every TestNG class once `@BeforeClass` runs.

This way you can work in only one Chrome window.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my BeforeClass method is static, so how to use the driver created by this one `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` in all my Test Methods?

Comment: Any test class which does not have ChromeDriver instantiation method in it but it requires `driver` instance in the class to run test cases. You can get this by `WebDriver driver = YourTestClassNameWhichHasChromeDriverInstantiationLogic.beforeClassMethod();` but this will open new Chrome window per test class. The best way is to use `Singleton` design pattern for your requirement.

Comment: I have fixed it by using `driver = new ChromeDriver();` instead of  ` WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` in beforeclass method 
But now the problem is that i get one chrome driver it's ok for my tests but at some time it didn't load in the second test so that a new chrome window is opened than it continue in the same one.
So now the problem in driver.get('url'); i have to work on it